# Seekbar visibility callback with AVPlayerViewController in tvOS

Tags: avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm working on a solution to display some elements on screen while the seekbar is visible.

I have a AVPlayerViewController with a AVPlayer playing a video. I want to display some components while the seekbar is visible and hide them when the seekbar is hidden.

Is there a way to be notified when the seekbar is visible/hidden?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate` specifically this method:

```
optional func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, willTransitionToVisibilityOfTransportBar visible: Bool, with coordinator: AVPlayerViewControllerAnimationCoordinator)
```

More information can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontrollerdelegate/2876484-playerviewcontroller

Comment: is there a way to detect this on iOS? I want to move my subtitles when the controls are visible